How to attach two instance schedules to one compute instance in Google Cloud?
I have a Compute Instance on Google Cloud which had an instance schedule attached which launched it on every Monday at 12:00. Then, I needed it to also launch every 1st day of the Month, in addition to each Monday. When I created a new instance schedule and tried to attach it to my Compute Instance, it failed and returned an error:
Invalid resource usage: 'Instance already has instance schedule policy attached. Attaching multiple policies is not supported.

I thought of creating a one instance schedule that would combine both schedule policies but I failed. When adding "00 12 * * 1, 00 0 12 * *" to the field "Start CRON expression", it highlights with red and says "Invalid cron format".
So the question is: how do I combine two schedule policies and attach them to the same Cloud Compute Instance?

As mentioned in the official documentation there is a limitation that  one VM instance can only appear in a single Instance schedule. So you cannot add multiple schedules to one instance that is the reason you are getting the error Invalid resource usage: 'Instance already has an instance schedule policy attached. Attaching multiple policies is not supported and "Invalid cron format".
There is currently a feature request raised to add a feature which can enable multiple schedules to one instance, you can follow this feature request or you can create a new Issue Tracker thread describing your issue. If you have paid support try create an issue.
AFAIK the only workaround is to look into using Cloud Scheduler or use 2 VM's for both schedules.
